# I am receiving a 503 when accessing the cloud datastore from a spring boot java app on a google cloud compute instance

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore

I am working on a proof of concept for a spring-boot java web app hosted on a google cloud compute instance using the google cloud datastore.

Here is what I did:

- Followed the steps on the getting started - sign up page

  - I did not create my instances via the command line, but created them in the console. I ensured that I added the proper scopes through the advanced settings.
  - Another difference is that i used an ubuntu image instead of the compute default
- I have the demo java code from here: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_java/ plugged in to my @repository

  - the only difference is that I removed the command line code and hardcoded my dataset_id
- I stood up the gcd local dev instance of the datastore set the appropriate environmental variables and was able to successfully execute the java code from within my web app.
- I moved the jar out to my google cloud compute vm

  - I did not set any environmental variables as the documentation says that setting the proper scopes should enable the java libraries to pull the config from environment
- I attempted to PUT to my resource (which uses the @reposoitory) (just like i did locally), I receive:

  ```
      DatastoreException(Backend Error): beginTransaction 503
      com.google.api.services.datastore.client.DatastoreException: Backend Error
          at com.google.api.services.datastore.client.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:115)
          at com.google.api.services.datastore.client.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:81)
          at com.google.api.services.datastore.client.BaseDatastoreFactory$RemoteRpc.call(BaseDatastoreFactory.java:41)
          at com.google.api.services.datastore.client.Datastore.beginTransaction(Datastore.java:77)

          ... more
  ```

I researched a few other issues like this on stack overflow, and the answers have been:

- did you follow the steps in the getting started? (Yes, to the best of my knowledge, I have)
- Contacted Google support and they fixed something (Not a good answer in my book. I want to role out services like this and having Google tweak something without letting me know how i can affect that same change from within the existing tooling is not an answer)

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you share your dataset id? If you prefer, you can send it to me at the email address in my profile, and I can take a look.

Comment: i just sent it via email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sending my dataset id to Ed at Google Support, he noticed that there was a "zero width space" unicode character at the end of the dataset id.

I guess I was lazy when coding it up and copied it from the project's page of the Google Developer Console.

Re-keying the dataset-id/project-id did the trick.